# MP4 file not playingn html 5 video tag

Tags: html, html5-video

Some of the MP4 files not playing in html 5 video tag.But few mp4 files are playing.
Is there anything issue with bit rate?
Is there any limit with bit rate or pixel?

Comment: There can be, depending on the browser. It's worth experimenting with it. What's the bit rate of the video that's not working?

Comment: Data rate : 2132kbps.  bit rate : 2196kbps(this is for video)

Comment: Are you having the problem in all browsers? or just one/some in particular? which ones?

Comment: I doubt it's an issue with bit rate. That doesn't seem too unreasonable. Do they play in VLC?